# datestyle ignore format postgresql

Tags: postgresql, command-prompt, psql

I am trying to ignore an illegally formatted date in a csv file that I am uploading to postgresql through the command line:

```
Error: date/time field value out of range:"199999999"
```

The problem is, I cannot change the data in the csv file, so I have to find a way of importing this bad date as is.

Answer (score 1):

Use an intermediate table (`loaded_data`) to store the data you get from you CSV. Make sure all the columns in that table are of type `text`, so that PostgreSQL will accept *virtually anything* (unless you have rows with the incorrect number of columns).

Once you have all your data in that table, *sanitize* all the columns so that when their values are incorrect you either set them to `NULL`, discard them (`DELETE` them) or set those columns to a default value. What you actually do will depend on your particular application.

The simplest (although probably not the fastest) way to sanitize your data is to use a function that `CAST`s your text to the appropriate type, and handles exceptions if the input is not well formatted. For the case of a `date` type, you can use the following function:

```
-- Create a function to get good dates... and return NULL if they're not
CREATE FUNCTION good_date(date_as_text text) 
    RETURNS DATE        /* This is the type of the returned data */
    IMMUTABLE STRICT    /* If you pass a NULL, you'll get a NULL */
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL    /* Language used to define the function */
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(date_as_text AS DATE) ;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN  /* If something is wrong... */
    RETURN NULL ;
END
$$ ;
```

Note that this function's behaviour will depend on your settings for `datestyle`. However, it will work always with texts like `January 8, 1999`, and will return `NULL` for dates such as `2017-02-30` or `February 30, 2017`.

You'll do the equivalent for a `good_integer` function.

---

Let's assume you have this input data:

```
CREATE TABLE loaded_data
(
    some_id text,
    some_date text
) ;

-- Let's assume this is the equivalent of loading the CSV...
INSERT INTO loaded_data
    (some_id, some_date)
VALUES
    (1, '20170101'),
    (2, '19999999'),
    (3, 'January 1, 1999'),
    (4, 'February 29, 2001'),
    (5, '20170230');
```

... and that you want to store this information in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE destination_table
( 
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    a_date date
) ;
```

... you'd use:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
    (id, a_date)
SELECT
    good_integer(some_id) AS id, good_date(some_date) AS a_date
FROM
    loaded_data ;
```

And you'd get:

```
SELECT * FROM destination_table;
```

```
id | a_date    
-: | :---------
 1 | 2017-01-01
 2 | null      
 3 | 1999-01-01
 4 | null      
 5 | null
```

Check all the setup at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e7556bcb60c79d198936ad5d5965edba)*

---

Alternative: use some [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool] that can perform equivalent functionality. The scenario I presented is, somehow, a very simple LTE (load, transform, extract) equivalent.